# JUnit Paramterized test Json/Text

Tags: junit5

Hi I have 2 tests methods, that are almost same, but is one difference between them, I would like to create a parameterized test method that have valuesource json and text/plain, how to create a parameterized test from these 2 methods.

```
@Test
public void shouldTestReturnWorkInText()
{

    given().header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
           .when()
           .get(getContextBaseUrl())
           .peek()
           .then()
           .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
           .body(equalTo("work"));
}

@Test
public void shouldTestReturnWorkInJSON()
{
    given().header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
           .when()
           .get(getContextBaseUrl())
           .peek()
           .then()
           .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
           .body("message", equalTo("work"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two tests are different only on the last assertion (`body()`) so you can extract a variable up to `statusCode()` expression and then do the specific `body()` assertion depending on content type provided as a test parameter

```java
@ValueSource(strings = { MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
void shouldTestReturnWorkFor(String contentType) {

    ValidatableResponse response = given().header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, contentType)
            .when()
            .get(getContextBaseUrl())
            .peek()
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());

    if (contentType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)) {
        response.body("message", equalTo("work"));
    } else if (contentType.equals(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)) {
        response.body(equalTo("work"));
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported content type: " + contentType);
    }

}
```